# How to filter from array elements in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `Vue Js 2.0` where I'm trying to filter elements which is in array format, I'm to format if the element is single string something like this:

```
const search = this.search_by_name.toLowerCase()
const searchContact = this.search_by_contact.toLowerCase()
return this.meetings
    .map(i => ({
        id: i.interaction.id,
        client_name: i.client.name,
        contactName: i.contacts_association,
    }))
    .filter((item) =>
        item.client_name.toLowerCase().includes(search)
    )
```

I want to have `item.contactName.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchContact)`
But In this case `contacts_association` is in array format which throws back an error:

> TypeError: item.contactName.toLowerCase is not a function

My `contacts_association` is in following format:

```
"contacts_association":[
    {
        "id":431,
        "first_name":"Nikunj",
        "last_name":"Doshi",
        "address":"602-603, 6th Floor, Dalamal House,Nariman Point",
        "city":"Mumbai",
        "state":"Maharashtra",
        "country":"India",
        "pivot":
            {
                "interaction_id":139,
                "contact_id":431,
                "company_id":160,
                "created_at":"2017-09-23 16:42:56",
                "updated_at":"2017-09-23 16:42:56"
            },
        "company":[
            {
                "id":160,
                "name":"Bay Capital Investment Managers Pvt Ltd",
                "address":"602-603, 6th Floor, Dalamal House,Nariman Point",
                "city":"Mumbai",
                "state":"Maharashtra",
                "country":"India",
                "type":"Investor",
                "sub_type":"FII",
                "is_client":0,
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "id":431,
        "first_name":"Vikash",
        "last_name":"Kumar",
        "address":"602-603, 6th Floor, Dalamal House,Nariman Point",
        "city":"Mumbai",
        "state":"Maharashtra",
        "country":"India",
        "pivot":
            {
                "interaction_id":139,
                "contact_id":431,
                "company_id":160,
                "created_at":"2017-09-23 16:42:56",
                "updated_at":"2017-09-23 16:42:56"
            },
        "company":[
            {
                "id":160,
                "name":"Investment Managers Pvt Ltd",
                "address":"Nariman Point",
                "city":"Mumbai",
                "state":"Maharashtra",
                "country":"India",
                "type":"Investor",
                "sub_type":"FII",
                "is_client":0,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to have filters with `first_name` and `last_name`, help me out in this.

Comment: can your share whole data Object "this.meetings" with us, because i am not sure you need to map anything  first on for filter , I can go further if i have whole data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you're saying that `contactName` is an array of contacts instead of just one, and you want to match all meetings that have at least one contact in `contactName` with name matching `searchContact`?

Try this (untested):

```js
.filter(item =>
  item.client_name.toLowerCase().includes(search) &&
  item.contactName.some(c =>
    (c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name).toLowerCase().includes(searchContact)
  )
)
```

Also I should mention it's confusing to mix [`camelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for `contactName` and `client_name`, respectively. Pick one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It helped.